# Given a field for Content Profile for a user, how can I extract that field via code?

Tags: 6, users

I have a location field for a user that is created via the Content Profile module.

How can I access that field in code for the logged in user? Is it something like $user->content_profile['location']

I can't seem to grab this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to load the content profile node into a variable first using `content_profile_load`.

This should work:

```
$user_profile = content_profile_load('profile', $user->uid);
```

That will return an object ($user_profile) that you can call the fields which you've set up.
Use

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($user_profile,1).'</pre>';
```

to see which fields are available.